# What happens in Magento 1.9 if the browser window is closed during import?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, import, csv

**What happens in Magento 1.9 if the browser window is closed during import?** Is the import process simply terminated or does it continue in the background? I'm using Magento 1.9's built in feature.

I ask because it's always going to happen on that odd brain-lapse occasion and it's not very clear in the documentation. I presume the only thing necessary would be to recheck no error data was imported to the wrong fields and restart the procedure with the corrected import file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I last used the import/export built-in module of M1.

AFAIK, **this module uses an iframe with a callback system in order to process the bulk entries to import so instead of trying to import all the entries at once, it imports X entries at a time to avoid facing a timeout/memory limit issue.**

So, **if you close the window, the iframe callback will not work and thus, the import will stop.**

Take that with a grain of salt though and wait for others' answers.

Comment: Thank you Raphael, this is what i suspected and found after checking databases but did wonder if something was potentially happening in the background. Still got that minor doubt and will take the grain of salt! Accepting this as best answer for time being.